# MySQL Stored Procedure running slow

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have created the following stored proc in MySQL:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE temp_mold VARCHAR(30);
DECLARE temp_time DATETIME;
DECLARE temp_shot_ct INT;
DECLARE temp_shot_count INT;
DECLARE temp_shot_mold VARCHAR(30);
DECLARE temp_shot_cavity_count INT;
DECLARE temp_job_count INT;
DECLARE temp_row_count INT;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE temp_shot_counter INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE setup_time INT;
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT 
        (schedule_run_time*3600)/(schedule_qty/schedule_cavity_count) as shot_ct, 
        ROUND((schedule_qty/schedule_cavity_count)) as shot_count, 
        schedule_mold as shot_mold, schedule_cavity_count as shot_cavity_count 
    FROM `schedule` 
    WHERE `schedule`.schedule_cell = start_cell AND `schedule`.schedule_date = DATE(start_time) AND deleted = 0
    ORDER BY schedule_order ASC;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;    

SELECT COUNT(schedule_id) INTO temp_job_count FROM `schedule` WHERE schedule_cell = start_cell AND schedule_date = DATE(start_time) AND deleted = 0;
SELECT cell_setup_standard INTO setup_time FROM cells WHERE cell_name = start_cell;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS rst;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE rst (
shot_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
shot_datetime datetime,
shot_qty INT,
PRIMARY KEY (shot_id)
);

SET temp_time = start_time;
SET temp_mold = "";
SET temp_row_count = 0;

INSERT INTO rst (shot_datetime) VALUES (temp_time);

#Loop through cursor1 recordset
OPEN cursor1;
    start_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cursor1 INTO temp_shot_ct, temp_shot_count, temp_shot_mold, temp_shot_cavity_count;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE start_loop;
        END IF;
        IF temp_mold <> temp_shot_mold THEN 
            SET temp_time = TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,setup_time,temp_time); #Add standard setup time whenever the mold changes
            INSERT INTO rst (shot_datetime) VALUES (temp_time);
            SET temp_mold = temp_shot_mold;
        END IF;

        SET temp_shot_counter = 1;
        REPEAT
            SET temp_time = TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND,temp_shot_ct,temp_time);
            INSERT INTO rst (shot_datetime,shot_qty) VALUES (temp_time,temp_shot_cavity_count);
            SET temp_shot_counter = temp_shot_counter + 1;
        UNTIL temp_shot_counter > temp_shot_count
        END REPEAT;
    END LOOP;
CLOSE cursor1;

#Return records.  Will be used in ORM to loop through records on the PHP side
SELECT SUM(shot_qty) AS qty, HOUR(shot_datetime) AS shot_hour FROM rst GROUP BY HOUR(shot_datetime);
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS rst;
END
```

I'm not the greatest at using stored procedures.  This one is running very slow - it takes about 6 seconds to run.  The queries individually run in milliseconds, so I was expecting this to take 100 milliseconds at most.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong that's causing this to run so slowly.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this run quicker?  I can create a PHP script to do the same thing, but I'm trying to get better at using stored procs and functions in MySQL - and  this is far less code.  I welcome any and all advice.

Comment: It's worth noting that when using the MySQL Workbench, this procedure runs almost instantly.  I'm not sure where there's such a long delay when I run this in code.  I'm using the MySQLi library to run this and I'm pretty sure I have the code right.

Comment: `private function oa_chart($cell, $date)
    {
        //Get schedule of jobs
        $start_time = Controller_Planners_Index::start_time($cell, $date);
        $conn = new MySQLi(...);
        $query = "CALL getOAChart('" . $date . " " . $start_time . "','" . $cell . "')";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        $chart = array();
        while ($g = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            if ($g['shot_hour'])
            {
                 $chart[] = $g['qty'];
            }
        }
        $conn->close();
        return $chart;
    }`